# When run maven test, compile crash with module-info.java:[2,35] module not found: org.junit.jupiter.api

Tags: java, maven, junit5

I try to run the maven test, but whatever I change or add, it crashes every time with a compilation error.checked the module-info.java, added and removed dependencies, plugins from the pom, nothing helps.
What im doing wrong?
My module-info.java
`module name { requires org.junit.jupiter.api; }`
dependencies and plugins at pom.

````
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.0</version>
            <type>module</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                    <source>9</source>
                    <target>9</target>
                </configuration>
            
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.2</version>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>```
````

Comment: First why are you changing sourceDirectory and testSourceDirectory ? Furthermore a `<type>module</type>` does not exist. You should follow the default directory layout and put your `module-info.java` into `src/test/java` if you really want to test in module world.

Comment: Many thanks. Changed to default directory layout and it was compiled. True, there was not a single test, but I saw articles on this topic here) I will look further